# Dojo : Accordion open and close

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo, accordion

> Please ref : http://jsfiddle.net/n23F3/

I want to know how to implement open & close on the Accordion Title (Red tab). 
 Now the first tab close only after clicking on the second tab. 
I want to implement toggling(switch) on the click event. Can any one help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Accordion` extends the `StackContainer` which by definition only shows one child at a time.

You can use `dijit.TitlePane` to accomplish what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/RJc4k/

Comment: Hi, Thank you Craig Swing. I have tried out Title Group : http://jsfiddle.net/RJc4k/6/ ,but it didn't show the open/close functionality like http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/widget/TitleGroup.html. I need only active tab at a time. Need to close all other tabs , while clicking on a tab. Can you specify a solution? .

Comment: I wired up events and now only the content of one title pane is displayed at a time, but it also allows no content to be shown. http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/RJc4k/

Comment: That is fine. Thank you very much Craig.

Answer (score 1):

TitleGroup may help you for this, but I am not sure whether it supports multiple TitleGroups ie. one TitleGroup under another.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/widget/TitleGroup.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do that with Dojo's accordion component.

But you could try this one: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-and-css-tutorial-accordion-menus. Although not an Dojo component, but...

Hope that helps!