# DOJO how to close all panes inside in a Accordioncontainer widget

Tags: dojo

The following Accordioncontainer code. I am trying to close all panes. Please help me

```
  <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionContainer" style="height: 300px;">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Heeh, this is a content pane">
            Hi!
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="This is as well" selected="true">
            Hi how are you?
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="This too">
            Hi how are you? .....Great, thx
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dojo : Accordion open and close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734171/dojo-accordion-open-and-close)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with accordioncontainer. You can achieve what you want by using dojox/widget/TitleGroup and dijit/TitlePane as follows:

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox/widget/TitleGroup">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" open='false' title="Heeh, this is a content pane">
            Hi!
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" open='false' title="This is as well" selected="true">
            Hi how are you?
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" open='false' title="This too">
            Hi how are you? .....Great, thx
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I took a different approach, I had a complete implementation and just wanted the accordion container to close a pane if it's title bar was re-clicked, so I found the method that had the behaviour I wanted (actually in the parent class djijt.layout.StackContainer) and adjusted it by overriding the method in a new child class.

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/when",
    "dijit/registry",
    "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer"
], function(declare, when, registry, AccordionContainer) {
    return declare("yourproject.CloseableAccordionContainer", [AccordionContainer], {

        // tweak the AccordionContainer so you can close panes
        selectChild: function(/*dijit/_WidgetBase|String*/ page, /*Boolean*/ animate) {
        // summary:
        //      If the selected widget is already showing, hide it. 
        //      Otherwise perform normally.
        page = registry.byId(page);

            if (this.selectedChildWidget == page) {
                // If the selected child is re-selected, hide or show it based
                // on current visibility. Had to disable animation but could
                // be enabled by overriding the _transition method
                var d;
                if(page.selected) {
                    d = this._transition(false, page, false);
                } else {
                    d = this._transition(page, false, false);
                }

                // d may be null, or a scalar like true.
                // Return a promise in all cases
                return when(d || true);     // Promise
            } else {
                return this.inherited(arguments);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

With this class defined you should be able to do the following:

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
    <div data-dojo-type="yourproject/CloseableAccordionContainer" style="height: 300px;">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Heeh, this is a content pane">
            Hi!
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="This is as well" selected="true">
            Hi how are you?
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="This too">
            Hi how are you? .....Great, thx
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you use this approach to override normal Dojo behavior, make sure to test on all your target platforms, there may be side-effects you aren't aware of. Keep in mind that this is the whole point of OOP - extend instead of redefine, but you would need to delve into the Dojo codebase to work out what's going on and what you should do. This change looks pretty safe to me, and doesn't break keyboard input etc...